# How NOT to combine all CSS into one file with SASS and bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm relatively new to SASS and bootstrap. I use bootstrap with SASS and struggle a little bit with a concept.

I always used CSS like this: one base CSS-file with the basic layout (eq. base.css). Every template includes additionally a different CSS-file (eq. sitemap.css, team.css, news.css). This CSS-files only contain the parts of the respective templates. So I can overwrite the definitions in the previous files.

In SASS everything is compiled in one file. In combination with bootstrap I actually struggle with the concept I used until now.

Every time I want to add a new CSS-file to the existing definitions, I get an error because I have to reinclude the complete bootstrap structure. But if I reinclude it, the whole bootstrap code gets written into the additional files (eq. sitemap.css, team.css, news.css) too. If I include both files in my HTML-tree, the bootstrap definitions (like the whole normalize block) gets defined two or more times.

I have this setup:

```
- css
|-- source
| |-- base.scss
| |-- team.scss
| |-- vendors
| | |-- bootstrap...
└-- output
  |-- base.css
  └-- team.css
```

In base.scss I include the bootstrap stuff. I do also need the bootstrap stuff in team.scss, but not all the main stuff like the normalize things.

How do I achieve that? Is that even possible or do I have to switch my css needs by adding a css-class to the body tag (like body.team)? But then I have to carry the whole CSS stuff of every page in one file. Isn't this crab?

**Edit** to clear things up a bit:
This is in base.scss:

```
@import "settings/vars";
@import "vendors/bootstrap";
...
header {
    @extend .container;
    ...
    .contentbox {
        margin-top: $mainGap;
    }
    ...
}
...
```

and this is in team.scss:

```
header .contentbox {
    @extend .sr-only;
}
```

It's absolutely clear that "@extend .sr-only;" doesn't work in team.scss because of the absence of bootstrap. But if I include bootstrap with

```
@import "vendors/bootstrap";
```

in the first line of team.scss, I would automatically add all the standard 16kb bootstrap things to team.css as well. However, these definitions are already in base.css. So I would have a preventable overhead.

I think I know there is no way to say: "Hey bootstrap. I already included you in base.scss. So you don't have to write the whole main definition of yourself into team.scss again. But I need you because I like you as an usable framework. So please provide me the functions and variables anyway.". But perhaps?

Comment: If sass compiles all the files into a single one, you just have to include your "bootstrap" file into `base.scss`. It will then be available for all other parts of your code.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Exactly what @brewal said

Comment: Do you really want *many* CSS as output? From a performance point of view, 1 CSS is better (only 1 request to the server, recent browser still have ~4+ downloads of font, image, js, etc in parallel). There are exceptions like the site I'm working on where 3x25kB CSS are downloaded but CSS is huge and there are very very few images to download

Comment: @FelipeAls Yes, I want many output files. The filenames are just to illustrate the problem. Within the structure of the project there are some real complex subpages that need their own huge css parts. So why should all the other user download this if they really dont need it.

Comment: I think the best approach is to put all those functions, variables and classes you mean to reuse, in their own files. For the classes, rename them as placeholder classes so they don't repeat unless you use them with @extend. Example, %container;

Comment: Makes sense to have 2+ CSS if you've particular pages with particular rules :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in this case is to compile `base.scss` with Bootstrap and all the base code and my customized `_variables.scss`. Then if I want to add `team.scss` I just import the mixins and the custom variables that I will need to use from Bootstrap. Sounds great!

**but**...

Since `.sr-only` and other are just provided as classes instead SASS mixins, you can't `@include` it, like you could do with the `.transition` mixin for example.

So, for the moment if you are using SASS, you have 2 options:

1. **Import the Bootstrap module** with the class you want to extend/reuse

   ```
   //contain the .sr-only definition
   @import "vendors/bootstrap/_scaffolding"; 
   @import "vendors/bootstrap/_variables";

   header .contentbox {
       @extend .sr-only;
   }
   ```
2. **Copy/Paste the class** from the Bootstrap source and extend it:

   ```
   @import "vendors/bootstrap/_variables";

   // Copy/Paste the .sr-only class to reuse, very un-DRY
   .sr-only {
     position: absolute;
     width: 1px;
     height: 1px;
     margin: -1px;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
     border: 0;
   }

   header .contentbox {
     @extend .sr-only;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tom. The problem is not Normlize. This was just for illustrating the problem. I cleared some things up in my edit in the original post.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the "ideal" bootstrap should have all the features encapsulated in a mixin and should write all the CSS only if you would include something like "provideBootstrap.scss". But for now I learned a lot because I didn't know about including just parts of bootstrap would work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're searching for is named a **[partial](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials)** in Sass I guess:

> If you have a SCSS or Sass file that you want to import but don’t want to compile to a CSS file, you can add an **underscore** to the beginning of the filename. This will tell Sass not to compile it to a normal CSS file. You can then import these files without using the underscore.
>
> For example, you might have `_colors.scss`. Then no `_colors.css` file would be created, and you can do
>
> ```
> @import "colors";
> ```
>
> and `_colors.scss` would be imported.

FYI, in LESS it'd be an [import option](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options): `@import (reference) "colors"`